# how to retrieve the msal object from cache location : local storage?

Tags: node.js, local-storage, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

First things first, I am below a novice level when it comes to Nodejs/msal/azure b2c and I am trying to understand the flow. 
I started off with this sample here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/
I am using msal.js with azure ad b2c in a Nodejs application. I am redirecting the user after signing in via sign-in policy to a different page where I have my other policies.

//index.html

```
var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, authCallback, { logger: logger, cacheLocation: 'localStorage' });
            function authCallback(errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
                if (token) {
                    logMessage(token + ":" + token);
                }
                else {
                    logMessage(error + ":" + errorDesc);
                }
            }
```

This is my onclick login function in the index.html. The 'test(accessToken)' method does the redirection to the backend node js routes where I store the accesstoken in a session variable and the method renders to a different page(test.ejs) where my other b2c policies are stored.

```
function login() {

        clientApplication.loginPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (idToken) {
            clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {            
                test(accessToken);
            }, function (error) {
                clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                    updateUI();
                }, function (error) {
                    logMessage("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                });
            })
        }, function (error) {
            logMessage("Error during login:\n" + error);
        });

    }
```

Now my question is how can I retrieve the current state of the clientApplication Msal.UserAgentApplication object in my other view(test.ejs) to do something like this :

```
clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                logMessage(accessToken);
            }
```